# Extract values in Pandas value_counts()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

Say we have used pandas `dataframe[column].value_counts()` which outputs:

```
 apple   5 
 sausage 2
 banana  2
 cheese  1
```

How do you extract the values in the order same as shown above from max to min ?

e.g: `[apple,sausage,banana,cheese]`

Comment: Could you please provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Did you use `dataframe.value_counts()` or `series.value_counts()`? What datatype do you have the output in?

Comment: Note that the output of `value_counts()` is a series, so any series methods can be used, but often you'd just save it as is, depending on what you want to do with it later.

Answer (score 134, accepted):

Try this:

```
dataframe[column].value_counts().index.tolist()
['apple', 'sausage', 'banana', 'cheese']
```

Comment: Awesome! On another note, when you print `dataframe[column].value_counts()` you get a dtype at the bottom. Is there a way not to get that?

Comment: Try: `dataframe[column].value_counts().to_frame()`

Comment: one more option `.value_counts().index` and `.value_counts().values`

Answer (score 57):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import pandas as pd

# Make example dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame([(1, 'Germany'),
                   (2, 'France'),
                   (3, 'Indonesia'),
                   (4, 'France'),
                   (5, 'France'),
                   (6, 'Germany'),
                   (7, 'UK'),
                   ],
                  columns=['groupid', 'country'],
                  index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'])

# What you're looking for
values = df['country'].value_counts().keys().tolist()
counts = df['country'].value_counts().tolist()
```

Now, `print(df['country'].value_counts())` gives:

```
France       3
Germany      2
UK           1
Indonesia    1
```

and `print(values)` gives:

```
['France', 'Germany', 'UK', 'Indonesia']
```

and `print(counts)` gives:

```
[3, 2, 1, 1]
```

Answer (score 28):

If anyone missed it out in the comments, try this:

```
dataframe[column].value_counts().to_frame()
```

Answer (score 11):

The best way to extract the values is to just do the following

```
json.loads(dataframe[column].value_counts().to_json())
```

This returns a dictionary which you can use like any other dict. Using values or keys.

```
 {"apple": 5, "sausage": 2, "banana": 2, "cheese": 1}
```

Comment: `sorted(dict, key=lambda key: -dict[key])`

Answer (score 2):

First you have to `sort` the `dataframe` by the `count` column `max` to `min` if it's not sorted that way already. In your post, it is in the right order already but I will `sort` it anyways:

```
dataframe.sort_index(by='count', ascending=[False])
    col     count
0   apple   5
1   sausage 2
2   banana  2
3   cheese  1
```

Then you can output the `col` column to a list:

```
dataframe['col'].tolist()
['apple', 'sausage', 'banana', 'cheese']
```