# How can I iterate over value_counts output that consist of two columns?

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to Pandas. I try to find a way to iterate over two columns (output from value_counts method). For the last hour I copy the values separately from the output which is of course pretty time consuming. I thought maybe Stackoverflow has a hint for me. Thanks.

Bachelor’s degree (B.A., B.S., B.Eng., etc.)--5786
Master’s degree (M.A., M.S., M.Eng., MBA, etc.) --1980
Some college/university study without earning a degree -- 1219
Associate degree (A.A., A.S., etc.)  -- 497
Other doctoral degree (Ph.D., Ed.D., etc.) -- 389
Secondary school (e.g. American high school, German Realschule or Gymnasium, etc.) --    269
Professional degree (JD, MD, etc.)   -- 54
I never completed any formal education  -- 49
Primary/elementary school  -- 41

Comment: Please share a sample of the dataframe with expected output.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35523635/extract-values-in-pandas-value-counts#comment111057657_35523820

Comment: Thanks. You saved me hours BigBen.

Answer (score -1):

Try putting it back into a dataframe